# Append pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a main dataframe (called df_main) with one column, which would look like this:

| Col1 |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |

Let's also say I have multiple other dataframes called df that I'd like to append vertically to this df_main with a for loop (and only adding the second column of df to df_main), so the main dataframe would end up looking like this:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Random | Random |
| B | Random | Random |
| C | Random | Random |

so, if I'd want to append multiple df to df_main in this format, how would I go about this? Something like this?

```
for file in files:

  df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=False)

  df_main.append(df.iloc[1], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: `pd.concat([df_main, df1['Col2'], df2['Col3']], axis=1, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: Also, if your other .csv files contain col 1, you could use `merge` to achieve that result. Otherwise, as @mozway states, `concat` with `axis = 1` is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks so much... this helped a lot. I'm now facing a problem with the column names. Let's say I have 60 columns, how would I change the column names considering I'm using a for loop? Using the pd.concat command, my columns are labeled as 0, 1, 2..etc